# In yii how to get success message after executing sql

Tags: php, sql, yii

i need to know how to get success message after successful execution of sql or failure message of wrong execution.my example is below

```
          `
     public function actionSql()
      {          
            $table_no='1';
            $employee='1';
            $status='1';
    $connection=Yii::app()->db;
       $sql="INSERT INTO orders_transaction (table_no,employee,status) VALUES(:table_no,:employee,:status)";

     $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
     $command->bindParam(":table_no",$table_no,PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $command->bindParam(":employee",$employee,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $command->bindParam(":status",$status,PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $command->execute();} `
```

after executing i need to know is the row successfully inserted or not.
i used below one but no use its only echoing successfully not failure

```
if($command->execute())
   {
    echo "Successful";
   }

   else {
      echo "ERROR";
        }
```

so i tried this one its giving **permission denied error for localhost with password" "**

```
          $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
         if($result){
              echo "Successful";

                   }

            else {
               echo "ERROR";
                  }
```

i hope you under stand my problem.please give any suggestion or answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Execute()
```

returns the number of affected rows(for INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE etc).

```
$num = $command->execute();
```

here $num will contain the affected number of rows.

Comment: thanks i tried this before itself.but thought wrong. one more thing if i insert empty strings to attributes its ins inserting null row with pk