# Extracting numbers from string using regular expressions

Tags: regex

I need to extract the numbers in front of Extracting numbers front of a string.

```
THIS IS THE STRING:
-----
DATABASE CONNECTION SUCCEEDED
Executed: SELECT MIN(written), COUNT(written) as ts FROM BGS.SettlementQueue
0 items are in the queue
-----
```

i need to get the numbers in front of  "items are in the queue".
the number has range from 0 to 9999

TIA

Comment: You post an SQL query, tag the question with JavaScript, and don't show whatever code you tried. What are we supposed to do with this?

Comment: `(\d+) items are in the queue`

Comment: Where is all this stored? In a variable?

Comment: The query text is part of the string i need to extract the numbers from...

Comment: If you work with PHP (We don't even know), this message may be the result of echoing the return of an execute(). As in this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577522/in-yii-how-to-get-success-message-after-executing-sql So... It may be funnier to handle this server-side.

Comment: "in front of Extracting numbers" -- What does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your string contains the exact text that you mentioned, you could use a lookahead to simply find the digits that appear before " items are in the queue" :

```
// Retrieve the number of items that appears prior to " items are in the queue"
var items = input.match(/\d+(?= items are in the queue)/);
```

**Example**

```js
var input = "DATABASE CONNECTION SUCCEEDED Executed: SELECT MIN(written), COUNT(written) as ts FROM BGS.SettlementQueue 10 items are in the queue";
console.log(input.match(/\d+(?= items are in the queue)/) + ' is the number of items');
```